# How to help doxygen resolve "matches multiple directories"?

Tags: c++, doxygen

In our project we have the following directory structure:

```
gambit
gambit/Utils
gambit/Utils/include/gambit/Utils
gambit/Utils/src
gambit/Core
gambit/Core/include/gambit/Core
gambit/Core/src
...
```

and so on. We do this so that in our files we have a clean include structure, like this:

```
#include "gambit/Utils/somefile.hpp"
```

where we compile with `-Igambit/Utils/include` and so forth. Now I would like to add doxygen documentation for each level in this directory tree. But how can I do it? I seem to be unable to avoid `warning: \dir command matches multiple directories`. For example, say I want to document the root directory, I seem to have no choice but to write e.g.

```
/// \dir gambit
/// \brief Root of GAMBIT source tree
///
/// Some long description
```

However that gives me `warning: \dir command matches multiple directories` because it matches the root directory, as well as both of these directories:

```
gambit/Utils/include/gambit
gambit/Core/include/gambit
```

But this is the root directory of the project, I cannot add anything to the path name to make it unique, because there is nothing to add! The same problem exists for the `gambit/Utils` and `gambit/Core` ambiguities. Is there some way to tell doxygen to prefer shorter matches? Currently it just seems to pick randomly between its options. Documenting the other directories with their long names doesn't seem to help, it looks like doxygen doesn't use that information to go back and resolve earlier conflicts.

Comment: When the file with the documentation is in the same directory as describing just `\dir` is sufficient and also `\dir .` works in that case. Would be nice when a relative path (i.e in this case `./gambit` would work, but the code might be used in multiple places inside the doxygen code so might be tricky).

Comment: Oh really? Okay I'll give just leaving it blank a shot.

Comment: For me it did work, I read the code as well. The documentation is not clear about what happens in case a `\dir` command is found without argument, it takes the path of the file in which the `\dir` command is found.

Comment: Ah ok so *only* "\dir" or "\dir ." works? "\dir ./Utils" does not work (from say the 'gambit' root directory)? That seems to be what I am seeing, and yeah that kind of sucks, means I have to scatter the documentation for my directories all over the place just so I can use "\dir".

Comment: Indeed the `./Utils` does notr woork either, the `.` is filtered out. In case of `\dir .` it results in the `\dir` so without arguments and goes automatically to the "default". At the moment the only possibility is indeed the scattering of the descriptions.